# implicit variables in R

Tags: r, scala

In scala we have the concept of an [implicit variable](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) or parameter, which can be handy, although sometimes confusing, in many cases. The question is:

1. Is there something like implicit variables in R?
2. If there is not, would be possible to achieve the same behavior as scala implicit parameters while calling some function in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved from comments.

If I understand this correctly an implicit parameter to a function is a function argument which, if not specified when calling the function, defaults to a default associated with that argument's type and only one such default can exist for all instances of that type at any one time; however, arguments in R don't have types -- its all dynamic. One does not write `f <- function(int x) ...` but just `f <- function(x) ...` .

I suppose one could have a convention that `integerDefault` is the default value associated with the integer type:

```
f <- function(x = integerDefault) x
g <- function(y = integerDefault) y + 1L

integerDefault <- 0L
f()
## [1] 0
g()
## [1] 1
```

There is nothing that will prevent you from passing a double to `f` and `g` but

- if you don't pass anything then you get the default integer which seems similar to scala and
- there can only be one such default at any point since they all go by the same name which seems similar to scala.  Also
- if no value is assigned to `integerDefault` then the function fails which is also similar to scala.

Note that `integerDefault` will be looked up lexically -- not in the caller.

Comment: I didn't have time to update the question before this answer since I realized later that in scala implicit parameters are looked up using the strong typed feature of the language, something unexisting in R. Yet I'll chose this answer as correct since it answer the original question and I would like to say thanks to you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the desired behavior is. From the first paragraph of the site you link, it seems to be simply a default parameter setting for parameters not provided to the function. This is used in R all the time:

```
> f <- function(x=10) print(x)
> f()
[1] 10
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: not exactly, this is a little bit subtle, default parameters also exist in scala, perhaps I should elaborate better the question, nice hat by the way...

Comment: Yes. You’ve got 2 close votes arguing that it’s “unclear what you’re asking”, so elaborating the question would be a good idea.

Comment: I don't see any close votes?

Comment: The votes are probably only visible to people who can vote (3000+ reputation). I can assure you they are there, though.

Comment: Actually, you can see close votes on your own questions once you reach 250 reputation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: Rather than posting a link to the scala definition of an implicit variable, please describe the problem you're trying to solve in R, including some R code that you have written, and explain why it doesn't do what you expect.  For guidance, please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post.